# How to set back button with arrow and icon and text in actionbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, toolbar

> I'm trying to set the back button in actionbar.
>
> I would like to set that like the picture below, and the whole
>   rectangular part would be a button to click to parent activity.

Settings in the Androidmanifest.xml or activity class would only display the default left arrow icon.

I don't want to create the custom actionbar layout to solve this problem because it needs to code in every child activities.

How do I set in the xml file or some other style.xml to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/. I see this tutorial is suit for your case